# Tracking Android app/device notifications

Tags: android, android-service

I'm writing an Android library where I want to track events like when user launches the app, when it goes to background, becomes active etc. I want to consider screen off as if app is gone to background. At the moment, I'm writing a service to achieve it which checks the Main Activity state every few seconds. I really don't like this polling like approach. Is it possible to get some kind of notifications from app when it changes it state. Just to be clear, since this is library so it doesn't have access to app's Main activity life cycle methods. I want my library to detect the change in app's visibility. Wondering if there is a better way of doing this than a sticky service?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "Just to be clear, since this is library so it doesn't have access to app's Main activity life cycle methods" -- have the activity forward these events to your library. Google uses this in the Maps V2 version of `MapView`, for example.

Comment: Idea is to library detect events like launch, foreground, background, end etc without app passing them over to library. I'm able to achieve this by using a combination of service and timer in it, which detects activity state every few seconds and logs events. I really don't want to use Service because its more like a polling approach which I'm not in favor of.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way you could achieve this is by tracking the logcat from a service. 
Your background service could be monitoring the logcat to see events of applicaiton launch and other events.

To read the log programatically you could do something like this

```
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
      String line = "";
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      log.append(line);
```

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives to service approach.

Comment: Well you could avoid service and do that in your app itself if you want to do all this in foreground

Comment: And note that your technique does not work as of Android 4.1, as you cannot read log entries other than those by your own process.

Comment: @blganesh101: I don't have control over app. I want to detect life cycle notification within library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to limit yourself to API Level 14+, you can call `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` on the `Application` singleton to be notified about those activity lifecycle events in some other object. Beyond that, there are no "notifications from app when it changes it state" that you can detect independently.